# Need help in translating VBscript code to java code

Tags: java, vbscript

```
For Each objFile in ObjFiles
            Dim Dir , text, filetocheck

            filetocheck = """" & objFile & """"
            Dir = """C:\Program Files\PGP Corporation\PGP Desktop"""
            Dim WshShell, oExec
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

            Set objExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /K pgpnetshare -v " & filetocheck )


            Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            Set oWmg = GetObject("winmgmts:") 
            strWndprs = "select * from Win32_Process where name='cmd.exe'"
            Set objQResult = oWmg.Execquery(strWndprs)
```

Above is the VB Script code, I need to write the same code in Java.Here, we are executing a **cmd pgpnetshare -v filename**
 I have tried like this

```
    //For all files and folders in directory
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        //Check if directory
        if(files[i].isDirectory())
            //Recursively call file list function on the new directory
            VerifyFiles(files[i]);
        else{
            //If not directory, print the file path

            String path = "C:\\Program Files\\PGP Corporation\\PGP Desktop";

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            rt.exec("cmd /K pgpnetshare -v"+ files[i]);



        }
    }
}
```

I have tried upto running command of Pgpnetshare. Can some one help me on the remaining part of the code. I

Comment: `rt.exec("cmd /K pgpnetshare -v"+ files[i]);` — probably there should be a whitespace after -v?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free porting service. That said, you can help yourself by indicating what the actual problem with the code is, rather than simply dumping a bunch of code here. If you don't know "whether the above code is right or wrong" you might do well to *try running the code* to see what happens.

Comment: @TagirValeev. thanks for your reply, can u pls hepl me in the remaining part of code.

Comment: As @MarsAtomic said, please try running the code first, _then_ ask about any specific problems you encounter. What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

its not clear what pgpnetshare is... but maybe this class will help:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public class Walker{

  private Path _path;

  public Walker(String p){
    this._path = Paths.get(p);
  }

  public void walk() throws IOException{
    Files.walkFileTree(this._path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){
      @Override
      public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path f, BasicFileAttributes atr) throws IOException{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /K \"c:\\program files\\PGP Corporation\\PGP Desktop\\pgpnetshare.exe\" -v \"" + f.toString() +"\"");
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
try{
  Walker w = new Walker("C:\\some folder\\");
  w.walk();
}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```